# How to change the number format of an excel sheet using matlab script?

Tags: excel, matlab

I am developing a m script which would write data into the excel sheet using ActiveX. I am able to select a range and change the Number format to 'Text'. But I would like to know how do I change the Number format of the whole excel sheet?

why I need this? -- Number Format 'General' shows Revision 1.1 and 1.10  as 1.1

```
e = actxserver ('Excel.Application');
e.Visible = 1;
eWorkbooks = e.Workbooks
w = eWorkbooks.Add
sheet1 =  w.ActiveSheet;
sheet1.Name = 'TestSheet';
eActiveSheetRange = get(e.ActiveSheet,'Range','A1:B1');
get(eActiveSheetRange)
eActiveSheetRange.Value = {'FileName','Revision'};
eActiveSheetRange.Font.Bold = 1;
eActiveSheetRange.NumberFormat = '@'; % Set the number format to Text
e.Quit;
e.delete;
```

PS :The code for adding the data is no included; I tried it manuall entering the values in the cell.

Thanks!

Comment: `eActiveSheetRange.NumberFormat = '@';` what is the problem with this line? Does it error?

Comment: Hi Dan, 
The problem with the statement is, it applies the Number format only for the selected Range. I wanted to know is How to apply the Number format to all the cells the sheets.

Hope this would help!

Comment: Well obviously it only applies to the range because you're calling it on a `Range` object. Just expand your range.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I was expecting if there are any other methods to do the same.